# Check for Existing Document in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongo and am using Mongoose as an ORM.

For user registration, I'm using email as the unique. I want to check if the email is already in use, and if it's not, then do something (perhaps save, perhaps next registration step, etc).

Sorry for what seems like a simple questions, but I haven't found an answer for it.

Unless it's "upsert". Which means inserting the document, even if I'm not quite ready to...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you asking how to find a document?

```
db.users.findOne({email => 'foo@example.com'})
```

If it returns something, document exists. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: thanks--just tried that and it worked.

 User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {      
      if (user) {
        console.log("user exists") 
      } 
      else {
        console.log("user doesn't exist")
      }

Comment: You can also use find function + limit(1)
https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/

User.find({email: email}, {}, {limit: 1}, function...